# How do I fix a layout at bottom and at top without hiding elements on Android?

Tags: android, layout, fixed

I'm having problems when using RelativeLayout, ScrollView and some LinearLayout to get some elements always on top and something scrollable.

This is my XML

```
https://pastebin.com/Uai2UynP
```

(I don't know why it got separated in this post but it's the same code)
The point is, when i add the `android:alignParentBottom="true"` to the RelativeLayout with the "always on top bar", it hides me a part of the ScrollView above. This can be solved adding a `android:PaddingBottom="[something]"` to the ScrollView above, but doing this it hides me something at the top, since I basically have the LinearLayout with email, gold and coin that i want too always on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout as main layout and use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in your layout which you want to place top and use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your next layour which you want to set bottom of your layout. I am giving you a Example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```